# how do i equate raw input with a variable value in python

Tags: python

This is my first 'program' or script or whatev. So if I am going about this completely wrong, feel free to make fun of me.
I wanted to make a textual, player vs player chess program.
My first instinct was to make the board an 8x8 list of lists like [[a1,a2...a8]...[h1,h2...h8]], but was unsure how to attach values to the items in the list, such as a flag for occupied or unoccupied.
Then I had the idea to try each square as a separate value that holds its status like a1 = wr (for white rook) and a3 = o (for open) and after successful moves just update the values of the squares.
My first instinct was to take the user input like

```
move = raw_input("enter your move")
```

and the user would enter:
e4 for example
I then wanted to do something like:

```
if move == "o"
```

to make sure the square would be open
I think its obvious what I am TRYING to do, but I understand why it doesnt work.
is there some way to cast the raw_input as a variable so that:

```
move == o returns TRUE if the variable e4 is o
```

?
edit:
for the actual code, it is really only in my head at this point but here is a shot:

```
a1=wr  
a2=wp  
a3=o  
a4=o  
a5=o  
a6=o  
a7=bp  
a8=br
```

and so on for the remainder files

```
move = raw_input("enter your move: ")
```

-----this program is mainly for me, so I am not checking input I would just enter a move like: e4

```
if move == o:  
  then e4 = wp  
  else print "illegal move, square is occupied"
```

I realize that the variable 'move' points to the string 'e4' and the variable e4 points to string 'o' and that these are separate and different entities, but is there some way to take the string input and check to see if there is a variable with the same 'name'?

awesome thanks for all the great answers...

Comment: `move = raw_input("enter your move")` sure likes like assigning a variable.  Please post your actual code and the actual problems you actually had when you actually ran it.

Comment: I think your question is pretty good, and a decent way to learn, but you should clean up the question some. It's a little hard to follow from the formatting and language that you use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you actually want here is a dictionary containing the complete state of the board --

```
board = { "a1" : "o", "a2" : "k", # ...
}
```

then you do

```
if board[move] == "o":
    # take appropriate action
```

Any time you find yourself thinking "I want to look up a variable by its name", a dictionary is very likely to be what you should use instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, but generally a rather horrid idea and frowned up - it's slow and hacky, almost never needed, and in some cases more error-prone/harder to validate and a source of security problems (likely not here, but still).

Rather use [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) - you don't need to change the bord representation, you can just (after checking if the input is in the right format), extract the number and the letter and then derive from that input the indices that refer to the field the user meant:

- For the number, convert it to an integer with `int` and substract one (because list indices start at 0)
- Map the the letter to the index with a dictionary like `{'a': 0, 'b': 1, ..., 'h':7}` (there are clever ways to do this with less code, but this one is simple and effective).

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, if you want to translate user input into variable names, you're doing something wrong.  Sure, you could use `eval()` but nothing good can come of that - it doesn't take much thought to find ways a malicious user could abuse this and make Very Bad Things happen.  Sure, you could write in a bunch of rules to validate input before doing this direct variable-name magic but it's a lot of work to make the wrong approach functional.  There's always exceptions but, as a beginner, you should just assume that this is a Bad Idea - once you learn what you're doing, you'll learn the exceptions, or at least the times when it's Less Evil to do so.

You're on the right path when you were thinking of using a data structure to hold your board.  There's plenty of ways of doing this - your nested lists are a valid approach.  To follow through with this approach, you'll probably want to write a function that translates from 'e4' to the location on the board, probably having it do the actual look up for you.  The next step might be to make a Board class & have this be a method of it (and then have a `move()` method, which passes off the logic to objects representing each piece type).

There's other valid ways of solving this, each with their own pros and cons.